# Does SpyOn Auto Call a Function? - Jasmine/AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I can't find where in the docs it would specify this. Here is the code:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$q_, _$httpBackend_, _$controller_, _$rootScope_, _ToolsService_) {

    ToolsService = _ToolsService_;

    $q = _$q_;
    deferred = _$q_.defer();
    deferred2 = _$q_.defer();

    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();

    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

    // these are all called when using $scope.$apply(), so spoof them
    $httpBackend.when('GET', 'http://192.168.99.100/groupReadylift/catalog-modals/please-wait.php').respond({});
    $httpBackend.when('GET', 'http://192.168.99.100/groupReadylift/catalog-modals/custom.php').respond({});
    $httpBackend.when('GET', 'http://192.168.99.100/groupReadylift/catalog-modals/paypal-standby.php').respond({});

    $controller = _$controller_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $rootScope.refreshBalance = function() {};
    $rootScope.user = {};

    $rootScope.validators = {};
    $rootScope.validators.gifting = {};

    spyOn(ToolsService, 'resetForm').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

    spyOn($rootScope, 'refreshBalance').and.returnValue(deferred2.promise);

    $controller('GiftingController', { $scope: $scope, $rootScope: $rootScope, ToolsService: ToolsService });

}));


it ('Should set $rootScope.errorMessage to "Ineligible to gift points." when calling $rootScope.refreshBalance().', function() {
    $rootScope.user.allowRedemption = false;

    deferred2.resolve([{id:1}]);
    $scope.$apply();

    $rootScope.refreshBalance();

    expect($rootScope.refreshBalance).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect($rootScope.refreshBalance).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    expect($rootScope.errorMessage).toEqual("Ineligible to gift points.");
});
```

The main thing to take away is that toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2) passes, even though I explicitly only called it once.

Advice?

Comment: Show us your controller so we can make sure the problem is not there.

Comment: @HankScorpio, your comment implies that it IS NOT supposed to automatically call it. Are you thinking I may have an init function that calls it?

Comment: Yeah, or a $watch or something that gets triggered when you run `$scope.$apply()`.
Whether or not it's "supposed" to do it is your call, not mine. I'm not implying anything though, that's just the most likely explanation I can see so far.

Comment: @HankScorpio, good enough for me. That's what I assumed, though I can't seem to find where that call is. Legacy code :/

Comment: well... can't help you any further without more information.
Some things to try: Set a breakpoint and see what's calling that function; run a global search for all references to `refreshBalance` and comment them out on-by-one until it stops happening; ooooor... run $scope.$apply() BEFORE you set up your `spy`, and after you create the controller to let everything settle before your test.